# Button font not matching storyboard font when I run app in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uibutton

I have uploaded OpenSans bold, regular and light into my Xcode project, set up all the fonts in the info.plist file, and set the button in the main storyboard to be OpenSans light and it looks like that in the main storyboard. Even on the storyboard preview the font looks like the light version of the font but when I run the app it goes to the regular version of the font. Does anyone know why this is?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- add your font files to your project in Xcode (“Target -> Build Phases -> Copy Bundle Resources”)
- In Info.plist file add the key “Fonts provided by application” with type “Array”.
- For each font you want to add to your project, create an item for the array you have created with the full name of the file including its extension (e.g. OpenSans-Bold.ttf). Save your “Info.plist” file.

  label.font = UIFont (name: "OpenSans-Bold", size: 30)

Comment: I did that and mentioned that in my post and it's not doing it. Here is the code I set: `upcomingButton.titleLabel!.font = UIFont(name: "OpenSans-Light.ttf", size: 10)`

Comment: if u did all 3 steps it should work .. check you spelling and uppercases

Comment: Oh on the name I had "OpenSans-Light.ttf" and not "OpenSans-Light". Now it works. Thanks!